# Xamarin iOS HockeyApp best practice setup?

Tags: xamarin.ios, hockeyapp

I'm attempting to get HockeyApp to work in my iOS Xamarin Forms app. I installed the iOS HockeyApp component (v4.1.0), and the getting started information for shows the following:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
    manager.Configure("Your_App_Id");
    manager.StartManager();
}
```

When I try this, `BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager` is null.

I've tried to wrap these lines in `HockeyApp.Setup.EnableCustomCrashReporting()` and `Setup.EnableCustomCrashReporting()` as is referenced in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15169/difficulty-getting-hockeyapp-working) post, but `Setup` doesn't exist in the namespaces I have.

What am I missing to properly enable HockeyApp in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoo hoo! Figured it out finally! I had the linker options set to link 'All assemblies' because of a suggestion from the [New type registrar in Xamarin.iOS 7.2.1, errors MT5210 and MT5211](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16489/new-type-registrar-in-xamarin-ios-7-2-1-errors-mt5210-and-mt5211#latest) thread. I was seeing the 'Native linking failed...' error and switching to 'All assemblies' initially fixed it.

Switching to 'Link SDK assemblies only' fixed both problems